# undefined method `item' with rails on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, registration, shopping-cart

I'm making a shopping cart with the following models:

**User:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  has_one :cart
end
```

**Cart:**

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items
  validates :item, uniqueness: true
end
```

**Item:**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

**Controller:**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        @user.create_cart
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

So it should create a new `cart` for each `user` upon account creation. I do, however, get this error when I make a new user:

```
undefined method `item' for #<Cart id: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Extracted source (around line #31):
29 respond_to do |format|
30   if @user.save
31     @user.create_cart
32     format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
33     format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
34   else
```

Why is that and what could I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Cart` model includes `validates :item`, which implies/requires it has an `item` column in the `carts` table. I suspect that's not the case.

Comment: Yup, that indeed was the reason. But how can I validate it that the `cart` can hold only 1 unique `item` without that line?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "hold 1 unique `item`"? You've declared that each cart has_many items.

Comment: By that I mean that each cart can have many items that can't overlap (i.e. a person can't add more than 1 "Freshly baked doughnuts" with a count of `x`) if he wants to do anything with them (change the count/delete it from cart), then he has to edit the item, but there can't be two instances of the same item in the same cart.

Comment: Then you want to add a uniqueness validation to `Item` with a scope of `cart_id`. See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness for more info.